# How do cloud services have access to your hosted script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, google-cloud-platform, hosting

Let's say you have some proprietary python + selenium script that needs to run daily. If you host them on AWS, Google cloud, Azure, etc. are they allowed to see your script ? What is the best practice to "hide" such script when hosted online ?

Any way to "obfuscate" the logic, such as converting python script to binary ?

Comment: There is no cloud, there is just someone else's computers. So if you are concerned about privacy and data sovereignty don't use a cloud service.

Comment: And yet enterprises big or small are using. And cloud services have been booming and making profit like mushroom after rain.

Comment: And yet lemmings are jumping of the cliff...

Comment: And yet I doubt there are many examples as lemmings. Remember the caricature on electricity or vaccine ?https://www.thatsnonsense.com/does-image-show-anti-electricity-cartoon-from-1889-1890-fact-check/ . Would you like to switch back to Intel 386, Win 3.x or get off the internet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can the cloud vendors access your script/source code/program/data?

I am not including government/legal subpoenas in this answer.

They own the infrastructure. They govern access. They control security.

However, in the real world there are numerous firewalls in place with auditing, logging  and governance. A cloud vendor employee would risk termination and/or prison time for bypassing these controls.

Secrets (or rumors) are never secret for long and the valuation of AWS, Google, etc. would vaporize if they violated customer trust.

Therefore the answer is yes, it is possible but extremely unlikely. Professionally, I trust the cloud vendors with the same respect I give my bank.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/security/privacy) you can find information regarding Google Cloud Enterprise Privacy Commitments.

It is described how Google protect the privacy of Google Cloud Platform and Google Workspace customers.

> You control your data. Customer data is your data, not Google’s. We
> only process your data according to your agreement(s).
>
> We never use your data for ads targeting. We do not process your
> customer data or service data to create ads profiles or improve Google
> Ads products.
>
> We are transparent about data collection and use. We’re committed to
> transparency, compliance with regulations like the GDPR, and privacy
> best practices.
>
> We never sell customer data or service data. We never sell customer
> data or service data to third parties.
>
> Security and privacy are primary design criteria for all of our
> products. Prioritizing the privacy of our customers means protecting
> the data you trust us with. We build the strongest security
> technologies into our products.

Therefore I believe is extremely unlikely that Google will check the content of your scripts.